Python script to a Microsoft store application
Hello i am relatively new to coding started with python and it made a gui i would like to turn into a Microsoft store app but i have no idea how i tried using VS 2022 as a windows packaging application but when i add my exe and png it says i need a reference to an application to "build" the project but under the solutions explorer there is no application directory any ideas on what to do to solve this or if anyone knows an easier way to convert a python TKINTER GUI to a Microsoft store application (at least to submit it there ) i would appreciate it
Ps: i have already made it into an .exe using pyinstaller
Thank you all in advance
I tried converting an python application that i made into an exe
To a Microsoft store application but virtual studio inside the solutions explorer has no application directory
